# I can't insert stock's data into my database

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

```
def connect(date1,volumn1,price1,rise1,time1):
    #print type(date1),volumn1,price1,rise1,time1
    db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","998426","stock")
    cursor=db.cursor()
    sql=" insert into tab1(date,volumn,price,rise,time) values(%s,%s,%f,%s,%s)"%(date1,volumn1,price1,rise1,time1)
    #sql = "insert into tab1(date,volumn,price,rise,time) values('2017/9/13 星期二','200',17.5,'2.14%','15:30')"    //this can work!
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()
    db.close()
```

date1,volumn1,rise1,time1 are string;

price1 is float;

Comment: volumn is like a cross between volume and column?

Answer (score 0):

```
    sql="insert into stock_CB(dates,volumn,price,rise,times) values('%s','%s',%f,'%s','%s')" % (date1.encode("utf-8"),volumn1.encode("utf-8"),price1,rise1.encode("utf-8"),time1.encode("utf-8"))
```

It can work when i change it.